# Alternatives to MAP estimator

Tags: estimation

Given some data $y$, dependent on parameter $\theta$, I have some density $p(\theta | y)$. I now want to infer what value of $\theta$ is most `likely' to have originated $y$. One possibility of doing this is calculating the MAP estimate of $\theta$. However, I was wondering if there are other ways of finding candidates for $\theta$, preferably in a Bayesian setting?

Comment: The mean of the posterior sample, the median ... For a discussion of Bayesian estimation [see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator).

Comment: Yes I agree with procrastinator. Bayesians believe that the posterior distribution characterizes our current knowledge of theta and so if you want a point estimate you have many choices, mean, median and mode have already been mentioned. A from of trimmed mean might be another possibility. In the frequency setting there is method of moments and maximum likelihood. Perhaps the shape of the a posteriori distribution could dictate the choice much like frequentists choose based on what best represents the center of the distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of estimator really depends on how you plan to use it afterwards. Each of the common estimators are associated with a particular loss function which specifies what you are interested in capturing. For example, the posterior mean minimizes the mean squared error (MSE), the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator) mentioned by Procrastinator (in the comments) gives a more thorough discussion.